# Can coffee pods be brewed in cup?

Tags: brewing-process, pods

I have a plenty of coffee pods but our coffee machine is currently broken.

Can I simply drop the coffee pod into the cup and deluge it with hot water, such as tee bags, or how many people are preparing the ground coffee?

Or because of the structure of those coffee pods they can be brewed only under pressure?

Comment: How about tearing out the pod in a standard filter, and just pour hot water for a standard drip? Pods contain finely ground coffee, so they are best suited for water that "passes" quickly (like in an espresso machine). Just bathing in hot water should work, but you get a pool of everything (flavour, caffeine, oils).

Comment: @EricPlaton this is also an interesting idea

Comment: Downside of going for dripping is the extra cost, though...

Comment: Tangentially related:  http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/81/why-isnt-coffee-commonly-sold-in-sachets-like-tea-bags

Answer (score 3):

The way I understand your explanation this should, in essence, make a turkish brew. In other words, it can be done, no problem.

The thing to consider would be your personal preference; not everyone likes to have their grounds swimming in their coffee, so as mentioned in the comments, pouring the insides into a drip filter might be an option to consider. If you do however decide for a turkish brew, remember to let it sit for a while so all the grounds settle at the bottom, and don't drink the last part (where the grounds will be)*.

*Or do, if you really want to. Almost no one does this as it tastes horrible, but my grandma actually used to eat the grounds at the bottom with some sugar, so I guess exceptions exist...